# Where can I get Appium compatible iOS app file for my iOS project?

Tags: ios, build, automation, appium

I am developing an iOS native application and I need to get the .app file which will be compatible with Appium to perform test automation. 
From where can I get that?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the location of `.app` file which will be compatible with Appium in-order to run automated tests.

```
/Users/<Username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<AppName>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option,

You can archive the project and once archived please follow the below steps,

```
Xcode -> Window -> Organizer -> See your archived file -> Right click to get the location -> Right click on archive file -> Show Package Contents -> Products -> .app file
```